# Using Enum and generics to get day of the week in typescript

Tags: typescript, enums, typescript-generics

I have an assignment to do in typescript to get the current day of the week in typescript using enum and generics. I have created an enum of the days, but while indexing it using a generic type it is throwing an error.

Here is the code

```
enum Days{
    SUNDAY = 1,
    MONDAY,
    TUESDAY,
    WEDNESDAY,
    THURSDAY,
    FRIDAY,
    SATURDAYS
}

function getToday<T,K extends keyof T>(days:T, key: K){
    return days[key];
}

let today = new Date().getDay();
console.log(getToday(Days, today)); //error
```

The error is

```
Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type '"SUNDAY" | "MONDAY" | "TUESDAY" | "WEDNESDAY" | "THURSDAY" | "FRIDAY" | "SATURDAYS"'.
```

Comment: why does it need to be generic? Wouldn't `getToday(key: Days){ return days[key] }` suffice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works, also `new Date().getDay();` returns the day in the form of numbers starting from `Monday` at position 1 so your `enum Days` should also reflect it.

You would not need to have another generic type for days as `new Date().getDay();` always returns a number and you use it to index the enum.

```
enum Days {
    SUNDAY,
    MONDAY,
    TUESDAY,
    WEDNESDAY,
    THURSDAY,
    FRIDAY,
    SATURDAYS,
    
}

function getToday<T>(type: T, day: number): T[keyof T] {
    const casted = day as keyof T;
    return type[casted];
}
let today = new Date().getDay();
console.log(getToday(Days, today));

// returns "WEDNESDAY"
```

Comment: It should start with SUNDAY = 0 since getDay() actually goes from 0 to 6 starting on SUNDAY
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDay